# Configuring wso2 ldap: read binary attributes

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I am configuring WSO2 with ldap and want to read the "objectGUID" property which is a binary attribute in LDAP. Is there a way to get this data?

Answer (score 2):

We can read binary attributes with the property as below.

`<Property name="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary">objectGUID</Property>`

However due to the objectGUID's encoding, it won't be shown by its actual value(as a UUID) in the latest GA releases.

Showing objectGUID as a UUID is also fixed for the upcoming release (5.4.0) and more details can be found in this [JIRA](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-6037). In case you are interested you can try this out in the latest pre-releases for IS 5.4.0 from [here](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases).

Comment: Is there a  way to add multiple binary attributes?

Answer (score 0):

On newer wso2 releases the setting can be found in deployment.toml:

```
[user_store]
ldap_binary_attributes= "objectGUID AnotherObjectGUID"
```